# Accessing fields of nested structures

Tags: c, struct

```
  struct    new
  {
  struct     A     var1 ;
  struct     B     var2 ;
  };


  struct     new      var3 ;
  struct     new     *var3ptr ;

  var3ptr    =    &var3  ; //assign the address to pointer.
```

How to access the variables of struct A using the pointer var3ptr .

Thanks
Naveen

Comment: You can't use "new" as the name of your structure. It is already part of the C++ language. Your code above won't compile.

Comment: @JoséX. In **C** the word `new` is not reserved. It can be used as an identifier. Observe that the tags of the question include `c` and `struct` but not `c++`. However, it is not recomended to use "new" if the code has a chance of being incorporated to a `c++` project.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean just go to the inner variables then

```
var3ptr->var1;
var3ptr->var2;
```

for example if

```
struct     A
{
    int x;
};

struct     B
{
    int y;
};
```

then you can do

```
printf("%d", var3ptr->var1.x);
printf("%d", var3ptr->var2.y);
```